# Check for specific errors in MySQL queries with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

Is there a way that I can check for specific errors in MySQL with PHP? For example, I want to run a query that inserts 1000 last names into a database table, and want to be able to detect any errors and handle them.

I know that I can use `mysql_error()` to check for errors, but I want to specifically check for a `duplicate value` error only. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could compare the error message. There is also `mysql_errno()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php. You could find the exact error num for *Duplicate Value* from the MySQL spec for a better comparison.